# Mock a method without arguments but with implicit parameters

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest, scalamock

```
abstract trait MyApi {

  def getResult()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[String]

}
```

The following **doesn't** work:

```
val m = mock[MyApi]
(m.getResult _).expects() returning "..."
```

It fails with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.scalamock.MockFunction1 cannot be cast to org.scalamock.MockFunction0
```

Note: the example given in http://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/ is only useful if the method has at least one argument. So we can't use the solution as in [mocking methods which use ClassTag in scala using scalamock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046741/mocking-methods-which-use-classtag-in-scala-using-scalamock)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't look at the right example, I guess.  Look at example 4 for implicit parameters:

```
class Codec()

trait Memcached {
  def get(key: String)(implicit codec: Codec): Option[Int]
}

val memcachedMock = mock[Memcached]

implicit val codec = new Codec
(memcachedMock.get(_ : String)(_ : Codec)).expects("some_key", *).returning(Some(123))
```

In your case, of course, the non-implicit params are null, so you want:

```
(m.getResult()(_: ExecutionContext)).expects(*) returning "..."
```

Comment: The solution is: (m.getResult()(_: ExecutionContext)).expects(*) returning "...", if you update your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the cases. If someone tries to do the same with more params the snippet is the following:

```scala
trait MemcachedV2 {
   def get(key: String, value: String)(implicit codec: Codec): Option[Int]
}

val memcachedMock2 = mock[MemcachedV2]

(memcachedMock2.get(_, _)(_))
   .expects("some_key","another value", *)
   .returning(Some(123))
```